# Write data from two arrays in one document

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have some data to be combined in one document in the mongoDB.
   I have two arrays

```
const users = ['Anna', 'Jack', 'Paul', 'Elena']
const additionalData = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5']

for(const i of users){
    const user = {
      username: i.username
  };
  for(const key of additionalData){
    user.keyword = key
  }
  await User.create(model)
}

[
 {
  username: 'Anna',
  keyword: 'data1'
 },
 {
  username: 'Jack',
  keyword: 'data2'
 },
 {
  username: 'Paul',
  keyword: 'data3'
 },
 {
  username: 'Elena',
  keyword: 'data4'
 }
]
```

I need to combine those arrays in the one document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, You just need to loop through `users` and get data from `additionalData` with the current index. You can achieve this in 2 ways

**Native Way**

```js
const users = ['Anna', 'Jack', 'Paul', 'Elena'];
const additionalData = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5'];

const newArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i += 1) {
const user = users[i];
const obj = { userName: user, keyword: additionalData[i] || null };
newArray.push(obj);
}
console.log(newArray);
```

**ES6 Way**

```js
const users = ['Anna', 'Jack', 'Paul', 'Elena'];
const additionalData = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5'];

const result = users.map((r, i) => {
const obj = { userName: r, keyword: additionalData[i] || null };
return obj;
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Users and additionalData array
const users = ['Anna', 'Jack', 'Paul', 'Elena'];
const additionalData = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5'];

// Merge them with this
$.merge( $.merge( [], users ), additionalData );
```

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer could benefit from an explanation.